# How react native mobile Apps save data locally?

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

I have an issue about storing data inside a mobile application? I know we can store our data locally using Async Storage. But the storage space is mush smaller in async storage.

My question is, there are mobile apps which we can use without internet connection. But there are huge amount of data such as, text data, imgae data etc inside that app. What are the options we have to implement that kind of application using react native?

Answer (score 0):

You can use local databases like `SQLite`, `Realm (MongoDB)`

Answer (score 0):

React native sync storage is a good option. Follow this [link](https://medium.com/@sajjadintel/react-native-sync-storage-c69062c234f)